# Calibre EPUB metada

Tags: python, xml, epub, calibre

I'm writing a python code to generate EPUB 2.01 OPF file (for compatibility reasons) and been searching for an exhaustive list of Calibre meta tag names. The following is a sample OPF that I use for reference:

```
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="2.0" unique-identifier="BookId">
  <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:calibre="http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net/2009/metadata" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
    ...
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
    <dc:title>Hairy Botcher and the Little Lamb</dc:title>
    ...
    <meta name="calibre:series" content="Hairy Botcher"/>
    <meta name="calibre:series_index" content="3.0"/>
    <meta name="cover" content="cover"/>
  </metadata>
```

Other meta names I found so far are `calibre:timestamp`, `calibre:title_sort`, `calibre:author_link_map`, which I haven't a clue how to use them. I even not sure if I use the `calibre:series` and `calibre:series_index` right.

Are there more tags I didn't know about? Where can I find the specs?

Tried `http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net/2009/metadata` like listed on the namespace list, but no avail.

Comment: Why do you care about calibre tags? They aren't part of the [EPUB 2.01 OPF spec](https://idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPF_2.0_latest.htm). If you're using calibre itself, it should be able to handle generic opf files, without requiring any application-specific tags.